# Changing console app icon (visual studio code)

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-5

Long story made short, how can I change the icon for a console app in VS Code (.Net 5)? Does it have to be done in the `.csproj` file?  Or is there a command or wizard to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<ApplicationIcon Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' ">x86.ico</ApplicationIcon>
<ApplicationIcon Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' ">x64.ico</ApplicationIcon>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Edit: Although, when you compile your application, you have the option to choose an icon for it.